# Types 'X' and X' both use the XML type name, 'X', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, xml-serialization

**I am receiving the below exception when deserializing one of my DTO's, is there ANY way around this without having to use IXmlSerializable?**

"Types 'RRA.Core.Services.DataContracts.ReferenceData.Status' and 'RRA.Core.Services.DataContracts.AR.Status' both use the XML type name, 'Status', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type."

**Here is the DTO:**

```
namespace RRA.Core.Services.DataContracts.AR
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    /// <summary>
    /// Status data object
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract]
    public class Status : RRA.Core.Services.DataContracts.ReferenceData.Status
    {
    }
}
```

****UPDATE/SOLUTION****

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946405/inheriting-existing-net-class-serialization-error) fixed the particular issue I was having.

Comment: Look here http://www.johnsoer.com/blog/?p=506

Comment: Have you tried doing what it asks, and adding xml attributes to give them each a unique name and/or namespace? Also: are you using `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer` with this?

Comment: This **[post][1]** solved the problem for me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946405/inheriting-existing-net-class-serialization-error

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946405/inheriting-existing-net-class-serialization-error) fixed the particular issue I was having.

Answer (score 3):

Your two classes have the exact same name. In C# that's okay, because they're in different namespaces - one is in RRA.Core.Services.DataContracts.AR and one is in RRA.Core.Services.DataContracts.ReferenceData. You need to do the same thing for your XML.

On both Status classes, set the Namespace and Name properties of the DataContract attribute to differentiate between them.

Comment: The link you said worked does the exact same thing as this, with the addition that it also changes the element name. You can still use DataContract attribute and set both the Namespace and Name properties to get identical results.